# How to convert string to array without ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, geolocation, location, coordinates

I have a problem when converting the coordinates that should be in array format, but sends me as an response a array but with the data with "" I will attach some images to understand better, sorry for my English.
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mxuf.png)
[expected response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn5AZ.png)

Comment: `arr[0] = arr[0].map(json_string => JSON.parse(json_string))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse() method to convert Json string to Javascript Array.
Hope this code will help you.

```js
const arr=[
  "[-19,-20]",
  "[-10,2]",
  "[-12,-20]",
  "[-1,22]",
  "[-19,-20]",
  "[-1,2]",
  "[-9,-2]",
  "[-10,2]",
]

const result=arr.map((item)=>JSON.parse(item))

console.log(result)
```